# Upgrade windows from 2012 r2 to 2019 will affect installed SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012-r2, sharepoint-designer, windows-server-2016

We have SharePoint 2013 installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 and we need to upgrade Windows from 2012 to 2016. My question is, will this process affect installed SharePoint or not, and what will we have to do before and after the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upgrade the version of the Windows Server operating system on a server that has SharePoint Server 2010 or later installed, use the process described below. In-place upgrade of the Windows OS with SharePoint installed is not supported.

1.Create a new server with the version of Windows Server you want.

2.Join the new server to the server farm.

3.Move services to the new server as needed.

4.If you're using the search service application, make sure you remove the search component from the old server.

5.Decommission the old server.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/installation-and-setup/upgrade-windows-with-sharepoint